# C#: progress change event in foreach loop no idea how to show progress with progressbar

Tags: c#, foreach, progress-bar, progress

Currently I am creating a video downloader in C# as i allow user to select multiple videos at a time to download and selected videos goes to a list view control. I want to show progress of each download. this is my code for starting download:

```
 listView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        listViewItems = listView1.Items.Count;
                        string path = Properties.Settings.Default.outputFolder;
                        IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(item.Text);
                        VideoInfo video = videos.First(p => p.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4);
                        if (video.RequiresDecryption)
                            DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
                        title = video.Title;
                        foreach (char c in invalid)
                        {
                            title = title.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
                        }
                        VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine(path + "\\", title + video.VideoExtension));
                        downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged;
                        downloader.DownloadFinished += Downloader_DownloadFinished;
                        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                        {
                            downloader.Execute();
                        })
                        { IsBackground = true };

                        thread.Start();
                    }
                    catch (Exception web)
                    {
                        DialogResult dlg = new DialogResult();
                        messageBox msb = new messageBox();
                        msb.labelText = "Video no longer available";
                        msb.btnText = "Ok";
                        dlg = msb.ShowDialog();
                        if(dlg == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            msb.Close();
                        }
                 }
                }
```

And this is progress change event:

```
private void Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
            pb.Value = (int)e.ProgressPercentage;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
        }));

    }
```

instead of creating for each item progress bar it is creating a lot of progress bar and these progress bar also showing no progress.

I am new to c# so need help in this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding the code a little difficult to follow without actually running it myself, but I would recommend breaking your problem into two parts.  First, ensure that the DownloadProgressChanged event is working as it should, meaning it fires every time progress changes and that e.ProgressPercentage actually does have a value.  And you shouldn't be adding a new progress bar every time DownloadProgressChanged fires.   Second, get some simple ProgressBar code to work irrespective of worrying about the entire list of items or even doing a video download.

Break the problem down into a manageable piece and then build upon it from there.

Comment: thanks for replying yes DownloadProgressChanged event is firing every time and e.progressPercentage has a value as if I use only one already defined progressbar it shows multiple progress result is flickering progressbar.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a progress bar every time the event is happening. You need to create one before the process starts, and only update it's value on the event.
sp `ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();` and  `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);` do not belong in the event.

**UPDATE**

I see now you want to add a progress bar per download.

You would have to move the 2 lines of adding the progress bar to the main for loop and then add a reference the each bar to each downloader. So basically you are adding one progressbar per download before the download starts, then on update you reference that own downloader's progressbar and update it.

```
VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine(path + "\\", title + video.VideoExtension));
downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged;
downloader.DownloadFinished += Downloader_DownloadFinished;
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(); //new
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb); //new
downloader.ProgressBar = pb;       //new - you will need to add a property to the downloader class
```

and then in your event you would amend that downloaders progressbar value:

```
private void Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            this.ProgressBar.Value = (int)e.ProgressPercentage; 
        }));

    }
```

Comment: thanks for replying I tried it but it gives flickering progressbar as it showing the progress of all downloads at the same time.

Comment: thanks for everything u have done so far as i am new to c# there comes another question which type of property should I add to downloader class as I try adding string, int but it gives error that u are assigning System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar to int. Need help please thanks again.

Comment: It would have to be of type ProgressBar. You want to assign the progress bar object to it.

Comment: okay sir i tried it with label as i can set property for text. but when i want to access it in downloadProgressChanged with this keyword it shows that ProgressBar is not defined in this program and also if i tried it by pb.text = e.progressPercentage.ToString(); it shows first one as 0.435% then it stucks then shows second label 0.456% and this label keep flickering as the progressbar if u understand please help me and i am very thankful to you for what you have done so far (Y)

Comment: Okay sir I created progressbar property and do as you say now it is creating exact number or progressbars as the number of items in list but progress is only shown in last progressbar and with flickering too. thanks for helping so far (Y)

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/30bl3km/9 this is the link of image of my software progressbars.

Comment: also sir u r allocating progress percentage to ProgressBar is it the property or the ProgressBar Control this is confusing and also whatever it is it is giving error if i write this.ProgressBar it says form does not contain any definition of ProgressBar any helped will be welcomed :D

Comment: I think you're having a problem understanding how scope works. check out a tutorial. http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx

Comment: sorry sir but my code is not working i create this property in downloader class like this public ProgressBar _progress;
        public ProgressBar progress
        {
            get
            {
                return _progress;
            }
            set
            {
                _progress = value;
            }
        }

Comment: and then call it in as  pb = new ProgressBar();
                        pb.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
                        pb.Size = new Size(158, 20);
                        pb.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        progressbarFlowPanel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                        {
                            progressbarFlowPanel.Controls.Add(pb);
                        }));
                        downloader.progress = pb;

Comment: this is giving error  progressbarFlowPanel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
              this.progress.Value = (int)e.ProgressPercentage;
            }));

Comment: Thanks for help anyway but it did not work 100% for me as i didn't get my desired results but i feel thankful to you for your efforts. it is possible i didn't get your code and can be my mistake. (Y)